# MEF method Equivalent in Prism Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

Hoping that someone might point me in the right direction.
I have been refactoring a WPF application that I wrote (fairly Complex - to me), to evaluate Prism and Unity over MEF.

I have run into an issue with the ServiceFactory pattern using Unity - that I do not know how to overcome. Being a beginner with all these technologies is certainly not helping any.

Is there an Equivalent way with Unity to get the Same result as the Below Code?

```
[Export(typeof(IServiceFactory))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    T IServiceFactory.CreateClient<T>()
    {
        return ObjectBase.Container.GetExportedValue<T>();
    }
}
```

Kind Regards and thanks in advance.
Stephen

Comment: Not sure what the expected result actually _is_, but are you looking for `Container.Resolve`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that the `ObjectBase.Container` property returns an `IUnityContainer`):

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
...
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    T IServiceFactory.CreateClient<T>()
    {
        return ObjectBase.Container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```